# Iterators validity and threads

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say that in the main thread of a C++11 program I build an `std::set`, fill it with items and extract an iterator `it` from it. After that, from another thread, I start modifying the set in such a way that elements can only be added to it but not erased.

Is the validity of `it` assured also while the set is being modified, or should I consider `it` invalid while the set is being modified by insertion operations from the other thread?

Comment: Good : [Iterator Invalidation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @Als: But that doesn't address threading at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes,Hence I added it as good read, not an duplicate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 23.2.1 `[container.requirements.general]`:

> Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.

For associative containers such as `std::set`, section 23.2.4 (`[associative.reqmts]`) says:

> The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not aﬀect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

So your iterators will remain valid after inserting additional items.

However, thread safety is a different topic completely.

Section 17.6.5.9 (`[res.on.data.races]`) provides that

> Operations on iterators obtained by calling a standard library container or string member function may access the underlying container, but shall not modify it.

Since that results in reading the container while it's being updated, **it is not necessarily safe to use a `std::set` iterator while inserting into the collection from another thread**.  Your implementation may provide a stronger guarantee.

Comment: This is under a single-threaded model. It is still possible that an intermediate state leads invalid iterators, if you perform concurrent operations such as `i++`.

Comment: Maybe I'm splitting hairs here, but do these guarantees include that the iterator is not invalidated at _any_ point of the invocation of the container member function? I.e., what's preventing an implementation from invalidating an iterator during a call to insert() and the re-validating it before exiting the method?

Comment: @bluescarni: As mentioned, thread safety is a separate topic.  I've since added what I believe to be the controlling requirement.

Comment: @BenVoigt: thank you very much, still cannot find my way around too quickly in the standard :)

Am I correct in understanding that storing the reference instead of the iterator th problem would be avoided?

Comment: @bluescarni: Yes.  Different threads accessing different objects is safe.